# Biojava secondary structure prediction

Tags: prediction, biojava

Is there any method to use in biojava to predict secondary structure from a given sequence?

Or if not does any anyone how can i implement it? any source code? Any exe to recommend?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not available in BioJava but what you can do is to do a BLAST search by using BioJava libraries (http://biojava.org/wiki/BioJava:CookBook3:NCBIQBlastService) or RCSB web page and from your BLAST search you can find a protein with 3D structure. Afterwards you can use `suggestDomains(Structure s)` method of `LocalProteinDomainParser` class in `org.biojava.bio.structure.domain` package. Domains might give you some ideas about secondary structures.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is secondary structure prediction from sequence in biojava. However there is secondary structure assignment given the structure, based on the DSSP algorithm, see https://github.com/biojava/biojava-tutorial/blob/master/structure/secstruc.md

Comment: Please note that link-only (or primarily link-only) answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow.  If you are able to include the relevant code in your answer, it will be received much more favorably.